# change height of a div change position of another divs

Tags: html, angularjs, css, position, css-position

I want to write something like this http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/EWJGJ/6/
with pure css but another divs position was changed 
I have some divs like this

```
  <div class = "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 lsl" style="margin-top:20px;" ng-repeat="rumorSub in rumor">
<div class="rumor-wrapper" ng-mouseover="rumorSub.show = 1" ng-mouseleave = "rumorSub.show = 0">
  <div class="rumors-bg">
        <div class="rumor-name" ng-bind="rumorSub.name" data-ellipsis></div>
        <div style="border-top:1px solid #ffb848;margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;"></div>
        <div ng-if="!rumorSub.show" class="rumor-short-text" ng-bind="rumorSub.short_text" data-ellipsis></div>
        <div ng-if="rumorSub.show">{{rumorSub.short_text}}</div>
        <div class="outer-rumor-time"><div class="inner-rumor-time">{{rumorSub.showTime}}</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: when i change the height of one div, position of other divs change i want to they are stay on their previous position and the divs positioned like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLye.png

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific of what you actually want by explaining the problem precisely in detail, so that the solution or the suggestions can be put out.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

CSS-class could look like this for the example you gave in the fiddle:

```
.contenitore:hover {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    top: -80px;
    left: -45px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:  all 0.5s ease;   
    -moz-transition:  all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Otherwise you have to specify your problem and show what CSS you have already done that we can see what you are facing.